# « D'ici quelques jours » ou « D'ici à quelques jours » ?

Tags: prépositions, standard, locutions

Récemment, je me suis demandé quelle était la formule la plus correcte entre « *d'ici quelques jours* » et « *d'ici à quelques jours* ».

Peut-on employer les deux formules ? Si non, quelle est la plus correcte, la plus usitée ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour citer le [Centre national des Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ici) :

> La prép. *à* est facultative pour introduire l'indication de la limite considérée; l'usage tend à l'omettre. *D'ici demain/à demain; d'ici janvier/à janvier, d'ici le 13/au 13...*

Par conséquent, les deux formes sont valides, mais l'usage courant aura souvent tendance à omettre la préposition.

De plus, je citerai également [une autre page](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3282), cette fois-ci de l'Office québécois de la langue française qui énonce de manière équivalente :

> La locution *d’ici* peut être suivie ou non de la préposition à. Dans l’usage actuel, on a tendance à omettre cette préposition surtout lorsque *d’ici* introduit un élément temporel exprimant un moment ultérieur.

Answer (score 3):

La réponse de Morwenn indique que l'usage tend à omettre la préposition.

Je ne peux m'empêcher d'y voir une légère différence de sens.

`D'ici quelques jours` n'implique pas l'instant présent, c'est un événement possible dans le futur.
`D'ici à quelques jours` implique l'instant présent, c'est un événement possible dès maintenant et dans le futur.